In which shastra we find lord Shiva chanting Radha Radha to make baby lord krishna happy
When lord shiva met baby lord krishna he first chanted Radha Radha to make lord krishna happy then lord stopped crying.Where can this be found in shastras

It may not be described in the Purana or other widely accepted Shastra, but only in the words of the Rasikas of Vrindavan. beda bheda jāneṃ nahīṃ neti neti kahai baina... –
